# How to programatically set the UIScrollView to be scrolled at the top

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

When running my app theres a gap on the top which appears to be because the scrollview isn't scrolled completely at the top (right under the navigation bar). 
I've tried a few things such as

- `setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:view.frame.size.width, y:0),animated: true)`
- `scrollRectToVisible(view.frame, animated: true)`
- `contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`
- `contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`
- `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

however none of these have worked for me.

My views are set up such that I have my root view, which has a scrollview inside it and inside the scrollview there is another view.
In the innermost view I have simply setup a few labels and text fields to play around with.

Any help would be appreciated.

The green part is the scrollview and the red is the view inside it, I simply put it like that as a reference point to see what's going on

[image: Layout screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE FOR iOS 7

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:
    CGPointMake(0, -self.scrollView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

your `ScrollView` should add a **ContentView** like this:

[image]

select your `scrollView` and in size Inspector bottom, set the width like this:

[image: my inspector setting]

for more details on how to handle `scrollView` in **Interface Builder** your can check out this AppleDoc [Working with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it somewhat centered the scrollview vertically and now the gap on the top is coming from the root view, see screenshot ont this link: (the blue is the root view) http://imgur.com/HSmGZD2

Comment: Can you edit  post show more implement code? have you use `Storyboard`?

Comment: I really don't have any code implementation, the only code I have set is to set the colours of the different views for references and setting the first text field to be first responder in the viewDidLoad() and yes I am using storyboard.

Comment: My hierarchy of views looks like this: http://imgur.com/LaLP8NS the way I've done it is I added all my labels and textviews that I wanted to test with and then I embedded them in a View and then I embedded that view in a Scrollview

Comment: Good job, so i think my answer is helpful.